# Get n filenames in a directory?

Tags: files-and-directories

I have a single flat directory with over a million files. I just wanted to take a sample of the first few files but `FileNames` doesn't include a "only the first n" option, and so it took over a minute:

[image]

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 9):

Using OS shells commands seems to be much faster, although their output will need some massaging to obtain only the file names.

For instance, the following works quite well on my system (Win7-64):

```
Import["!dir /b /a-d C:\\Windows\\*", "Text"] // StringSplit[#, "\n"] &
```

This command takes 0.11s to execute; for comparison the corresponding FileNames expression (`FileNames["*", "C:\\Windows\\"]`) takes 0.33s. The difference is even more pronounced with larger/deeper directories.

In the dir command above, `/a-d` selects files that are not directories; `/b` produces minimal output which is easier to parse. If you want to traverse subdirectories, you can use the `/s` option.

Comment: I have OSX 10.11

Comment: @M.R. OK. So have you tried replacing the corresponding Unix-style shell commands in the `Import` expression? Does that not work?

Comment: @M. R., then you might want to look up [the `man` page for `ls`](http://ss64.com/osx/ls.html).

Comment: i think youll need `find` to list files-not-directories.  `ls` will do fine for a specific extension though

Comment: @george, or use the `-p` switch in `ls`.

Answer (score 8):

New function in Mathematica 11 `FileSystemMap` with option `MaxItems` ([documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileSystemMap.html)) can be useful here.

```
dir = "C:\\Users\\Alexey\\Documents";
n = 10;
f = FileSystemMap[#&, dir, MaxItems -> n] // Keys;
```

Comment: Try this on a large directory with, it hangs when you specify a recursive depth. `n = 10; f = FileSystemMap[#&, dir, Infinity, MaxItems -> n] // Keys;`

Comment: @M.R. You are correct. This works not very good on a large directory. `FileSystemMap` and `FileSystemScan` are much slower than `FileNames`. It's very strange.

Answer (score 3):

a linux version using `find` to list files and `head` to take the first `n`.

```
dir = "/path"
StringSplit[
    RunProcess[
         {"/bin/sh",
          "-c",
          "find "<>dir<>" -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -10"
          },"StandardOutput"]]
```

note `find` does not return files in any canonical order, you can sort for example,
add `| sort` in front of `| head`

Note `FileNames[][;;10]]` is a good bit faster by my testing, but I don't have a folder with a million files to test it on.